# ¿Cómo contar repeticiones de caracteres de un String en c#?

Tags: c#, string

Tengo un programa que tiene que contar los caracteres repetidos que contiene un `String` (sin que el usuario meta uno para comprobar), el caso es que ya lo tengo hecho, pero queda un poco feo el que se muestre por pantalla toda la frase con las veces que aparece cada carácter al lado, me gustaría que sólo se mostrase una vez, pero no sé cómo puedo hacerlo, a ver si alguien puede ayudarme:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp8
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("exercici1.txt")) {
                    string line, copyLine;
                    char[] charUtilitzats = {};
                    char caracter = ' ';
                    int compt = 0;
                    bool trobat = false;

                    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {

                        copyLine = line;

                        for (int x = 0; x < line.Length; x++)
                        {

                            for (int y = 0; y < line.Length; y++)
                            {

                                caracter = line[x];

                                for (int z = 0; z < charUtilitzats.Length; z++)
                                {
                                    if (caracter == charUtilitzats[z])
                                    {
                                        trobat = true;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        charUtilitzats[y] = caracter;
                                        compt++;
                                    }
                                }



                                if (caracter == line[y] && trobat != true)
                                {
                                    compt++;
                                    trobat = false;
                                }
                            }

                            if (trobat != true)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("El caracter " + caracter + " apareix " + compt + " vegades");
                                compt = 0;
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error general");
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                Environment.Exit(1);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

Se agradece cualquier tipo de crítica constructiva referente al código, ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: podrias agregar una pantalla de ejemplo de lo que no queres y lo que queres?

Answer (score 3):

Si utilizas un `StreamReader` es porque estas leyendo desde archivos, entonces, puedes hacer que te muestre una única salida con la siguiente información:

```
El caracter 'x' se repite 'x' veces en la frase.
```

Esto lo puedes lograr con una de las tantas maneras que existen, te dejo una super sencilla que utilizar `Dictionary<Tk,Tv>` como base para contar los caracteres, está escríto a mano, por lo que puede traer varios errores.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

// Todo el rollo de la class program y eso...
public static void main(string[] args) 
{
    // Declaramos diccionario para almacenar las cuentas.
    IDictionary<char, int> Counter = new Dictionary<char, int>();
    try
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("exercici1.txt")) 
        {
            string text = sr.ReadToEnd();

            // Imprimimos la frase
            Console.WriteLine("Frase: " + text);

            // Iteramos entre los caracteres
            foreach (char c in text)
            {
                if (Counter.ContainsKey(c)) 
                    Counter[c] += 1;
                else
                    Counter.Add(c, 1);
            }

            // Ahora mostramos los caracteres:
            foreach (KeyValuePair<char, int> kvp in Counter)
                Console.WriteLine("El caracter '" + kvp.Key + "' se repite '" + kvp.Value + "' veces."); 
        } 
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error en la lectura del archivo");
    }  
}
```

Aunque está un poco incompleto, le falta soporte sólo para letras y dependiendo del gusto que tengas, puedes mejorarlo.

Saludos!